# How to use one single Prototype-Instance throughout multiple HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I created some Javascript "Classes" within their own files using the Prototype function like this:

```
function Playlist(id, name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

Playlist.prototype.getid = function(){return this.id;} 
Playlist.prototype.getname = function(){return this.name;}
```

I create instances of that "class" like this:

```
var playlist = new Playlist();
```

Is there any possible way I can use one single Instance throughout multiple HTML pages? I tried it like this:

```
"<a href='next.html?pl="+playlist+"'>Next</a>"
```

But that only gives me [Object, object] with which I can't really do anything.
I would greatly appreciate any solutions.

Comment: You can store strings in local storage, but that won't help with complete objects like you've got. Each new page completely wipes out the context, so every page has to rebuild from scratch. That's one reason some people design sites as single-page systems, dynamically loading new content *without* reloading the page.

Comment: No, the only way to keep the instance is not to switch pages and using ajax instead.

Comment: How utterly unrelated to oop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to pass JavaScript function instances over HTTP.  JSON will not help you as it only serializes properties and not methods.  You can serialize function *declarations* and recreate them via `eval`, but that is *evil* and does not do what you want anyway.

Two possible solutions are:

1. Keep everything on a single page.  Single page apps are very popular.  Load what you need to load asynchronously and you will still have access to the `Playlist` instance on that page.
2. Pass properties (`id` and `name`) that you need to recreate the object instance over HTTP instead, then create the instance on the next page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I will do the second one, since I've allready build the app over multiple pages.